# Simplifying with assumption

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to simplify below expression:

```
Simplify[( 
 E^(2 I t) Sqrt[
  E^(-4 I t) (dk ro ((1 + E^(2 I t))^2 ep^2 + 
        4 (3 - 2 E^(2 I t) + 3 E^(4 I t)) ep G v + 
        4 (1 + E^(2 I t))^2 G^2 v^2) + 
     16 (-1 + E^(2 I t))^2 G^2 v xr)^2])/(
 dk ro ((1 + E^(2 I t))^2 ep^2 + 
     4 (3 - 2 E^(2 I t) + 3 E^(4 I t)) ep G v + 
     4 (1 + E^(2 I t))^2 G^2 v^2) + 16 (-1 + E^(2 I t))^2 G^2 v xr), 
 G > 0 && dk > 0 && ro > 0 && Element[ep, Reals] && 
  Element[G, Reals] && Element[t, Reals] && Element[dk, Reals] && 
  t > 0 && v > 0 && Element[v, Reals]]
```

But it returns exactly the same expression without any change! What should I do? Could anyone help me?

Comment: "But it returns exactly the same expression without any change!" - that means *Mathematica* is unable to find anything simpler than what you have. Were you expecting something simpler for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExpToTrig` helps here, as it allows the cancellation of many of the complex variables:

```
Simplify[ExpToTrig[(E^(2 I t) Sqrt[
      E^(-4 I t) (dk ro ((1 + E^(2 I t))^2 ep^2 + 
             4 (3 - 2 E^(2 I t) + 3 E^(4 I t)) ep G v + 
             4 (1 + E^(2 I t))^2 G^2 v^2) + 
          16 (-1 + E^(2 I t))^2 G^2 v xr)^2])/(dk ro ((1 + 
            E^(2 I t))^2 ep^2 + 
        4 (3 - 2 E^(2 I t) + 3 E^(4 I t)) ep G v + 
        4 (1 + E^(2 I t))^2 G^2 v^2) + 
     16 (-1 + E^(2 I t))^2 G^2 v xr)], 
 G > 0 && dk > 0 && ro > 0 && Element[ep, Reals] && t > 0 && v > 0]
```

The resulting simplification contains a term of the form $\frac{\sqrt{\cos(2t)^2}}{\cos(2t)}$, which doesn't simplify with only the assumption that $t>0$. If we assume that $\sqrt{\cos(2t)^2}$ and $\cos(2t)$ cancel, then the whole expression simplifies to $1$. However, that's not guaranteed to be true everywhere.

As an additional note, if you assume an ordering operation like `t>0`, *Mathematica* automatically assumes that the variable involved is real.

Comment: When I use your code, the output is:  Sqrt[(dk ro (ep - 2 G v)^2 - 
  16 G^2 v xr + (dk ro (ep^2 + 12 ep G v + 4 G^2 v^2) + 
     16 G^2 v xr) Cos[2 t])^2]/(
dk ro (ep - 2 G v)^2 - 
 16 G^2 v xr + (dk ro (ep^2 + 12 ep G v + 4 G^2 v^2) + 
    16 G^2 v xr) Cos[2 t])

Comment: Yes, the `Cos[2 t]` term at the end of the numerator and denominator is the reason it doesn't simplify further. See `FindInstance[Cos[2 t] != Sqrt[Cos[2 t]^2], t, Reals]`.

Comment: If I assume $\frac{\sqrt{\cos(2t)^2}}{\cos(2t)}$ is -1, what does it return?

Comment: Hard to say, since that precise term doesn't actually appear. However, if you can provide an additional assumption on `xr`, further simplification into a piecewise function is possible. If `xr` is real, then the expression is always either -1 or 1, depending on how the terms compare.

Comment: I know that xr is real. Does it help?

Comment: Plug it in and see. The piecewise form resulting form assuming `xr` is real shows that it's always -1 or +1, but the condition may not necessarily seem simpler.

Comment: one of the conditions is true!

Comment: True is simply a fall through in this case: if none of the prior cases apply, then it is that case instead.